# Debugging / analyzer tool for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, debugging, analyzer, parasoft

Please suggest if we can use any static analysis tools for Javascript? Can parasoft tool be used? Any tutorial on parasoft would be helpful.

Are there any other debugger alternative to Opera dragonfly?

Thanks
Sneha

Answer (score 1):

**Static analysis:**

- [JSLint](http://jslint.com/)
- [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/)
- [Google Closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/)

**Debuggers**:

- Chrome Inspector ( `F12` in Chrome )
- (FireFox) [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)
- (Many Browsers) [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)
- (Mobile Webkit) [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/1.x/1.5.0/)

The `IE`s have a few debuggers, some come with `MS Office`, some with `Visual Studio`, its sort of a mess, and I don't have great resources for that.

Static analyzers for `JavaScript` are fairly limited because of the linkage patterns and dynamically defined objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to debug javascript for front-end web development, then the debugger that I find most useful is the IE9 debugger. I am aware that there is a lot of bias against internet explorer, but the debugger is really good and when an exception is thrown you would actually get a window for it.